# Problems communicating with MOVESENSE using adb

Tags: movesense

I have tried to follow the instructions from Movesense on how to do Whiteboard communication using ADB. This does not work as expected.

On a sidenote - I'm just trying to set up a handful of sensors to start some heart rate and movement measurement and store data to the logbook. After 30-40 minutes, I want to stop measurements and fetch the data from each device. My first dream was that I could do this using Whiteboard over BLE (from Matlab, Python, LabVIEW, ...) without having to use ADB or similar solutions. But I guess this was a bit too optimistic.

#### Setup

- Installed the adb tools: OK
- Enabled USB debugging on an Android phone: OK
- Tested that adb can install apps and handle the phone: OK
- Installed `sampleapp-debug-1.5.1.apk`:

  - Tried to install using adb: OK
  - Tried to install by copying the file to the phone and installing it there: OK
  - I got a message saying that the sample app was not compiled for the current version of Android (I'm using a Samsung S10e running One UI version 4.0 and Android version 12, security fix level 01.02.2022).

Im working on an Intel Mac running Big Sur 11.6.5 with plenty of resources.

#### What I've tried so far

First of all, I start the app and connect to the MOVESENSE device.

When trying the example commands from Movesense, I get:

##### Switch on LED:

```
fjp@fMac-19 sensorsw % adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MOVESENSE --es type put --es path Component/Led --es value '''{\"isOn\":true}'''
Broadcasting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MOVESENSE flg=0x400000 (has extras) }
Broadcast completed: result=0
```

##### Get Info

Get Info does only work if I place curly braces between the quotas. See results below for both variants.

```
fjp@fMac-19 sensorsw % adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MOVESENSE --es type get --es path Info --es value ''''''

Exception occurred while executing 'broadcast':
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument expected after "value"
    at com.android.modules.utils.BasicShellCommandHandler.getNextArgRequired(BasicShellCommandHandler.java:295)
    at android.content.Intent.parseCommandArgs(Intent.java:8329)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerShellCommand.makeIntent(ActivityManagerShellCommand.java:367)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerShellCommand.runSendBroadcast(ActivityManagerShellCommand.java:788)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerShellCommand.onCommand(ActivityManagerShellCommand.java:214)
    at com.android.modules.utils.BasicShellCommandHandler.exec(BasicShellCommandHandler.java:97)
    at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:38)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onShellCommand(ActivityManagerService.java:10429)
    at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:986)
    at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:860)
    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:6049)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3034)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1220)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1179)
fjp@fMac-19 sensorsw % adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MOVESENSE --es type get --es path Info --es value '''{}'''
Broadcasting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MOVESENSE flg=0x400000 (has extras) }
Broadcast completed: result=0
```

#### The suspects

- Is my problems due to an old version of the Android app? I could not find anything newer than 1.5.1.
- I tried to poke around a bit in the phone using `adb shell dumpsys activity services | grep android.intent.action`, and got a load of results, I then started to look for MOVESENSE as well using `adb shell dumpsys activity services | grep MOVESENSE`, and got *no* hits. I'm on thin ice here, but could it be that there should be an `android.intent.action.MOVESENSE` in there someplace?

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of trial and error, I have finally found a solution.

#### The solution

I found a[Bitbucket directory with a lot of precompiled Android apps](https://bitbucket.org/movesense/movesense-mobile-lib/downloads/).

The file `Showcaseapp-debug_adb-bridge-build.apk` is the one you want. Here is what you do:

- Download `Showcaseapp-debug_adb-bridge-build.apk`, and place it in your directory of choice.
- On your Android device, uninstall the Showcase app if you have installed it already.
- Install the app using ADB on your computer: `adb install Showcaseapp-debug_adb-bridge-build.apk`.
- Start the app on your Android device and connect to the Movesense device.
- Try a command like:

  - Switch LED on: `adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MOVESENSE --es type put --es path Component/Led --es value '''{\"isOn\":true}'''`
  - Switch LED off: `adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MOVESENSE --es type put --es path Component/Led --es value '''{\"isOn\":false}'''`

#### A final note

In a perfect world, Movesense would make wbcmd capable of using theBLE device built into most/all PCs, be it Windows, Linux, or Mac. Or even perfecter (is that a word?), make a variant that used TCP/IP instead of standard in/out.